# If a play ends with two runners at the same base who is safe?

Tags: baseball, rules

In baseball if a play ends and two base runners are at the same base who is safe and who is out? Does the situation change if one of the runners can be forced?

Comment: However, for rule 7.03(b), if the batter-runner is put out first by tag or touching first base before a play is made on the preceding runner, the force play on the preceding runner is removed and the preceding runner is not required to advance. Rule 7.03(a) then applies again.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Technically the play cannot end with two runners on the same base.

If two runners are occupying the same base, then the trailing runner is considered "In Jeopardy", or able to be tagged out, and must either retreat to the previous base or, if it is occupied, the leading runner must advance a base.

However, if the trailing runner was forced to the base then the leading runner is considered "In Jeopardy" and must advance or be tagged out.

Comment: [citation needed]

Comment: @corsiKa Sorry, I just _knew_ it. :) 

I saw this comment too late, but JW01 has the link to the rule.

Answer (score 19):

According to the [Official Baseball Rules](http://mlb.mlb.com/mlb/downloads/y2011/Official_Baseball_Rules.pdf) posted on MLB.com, rule 7.03 states:

> 7.03
>
> (a) Two runners may not occupy a base, but if, while the ball is
>   alive, two runners are touching a base, the following runner shall be
>   out when tagged and the preceding runner is entitled to the base,
>   unless Rule 7.03(b) applies.
>
> (b) If a runner is forced to advance by reason of the batter becoming
>   a runner and two runners are touching a base to which the following
>   runner is forced, the following runner is entitled to the base and the
>   preceding runner shall be out when tagged or when a fielder possesses
>   the ball and touches the base to which such preceding runner is
>   forced.

My interpretation is that the following runner will be out in this situation unless he/she was the hitter and was advancing to a base - in that situation, the preceding runner needs to advance or will be tagged out.

Comment: Not just the hitter. Consider: Players on first and second, hitter runs.  Hitter makes it to first safe, runner from first goes to second, runner on second doesn't move -- the latter is out.