# Which runner is out?

Tags: rules, baseball, officiating

There is 1 out.

There is a runner on first, and the ball is hit to the second baseman.

The second baseman gets the ball and runs towards first.

The runner on first stays on 1st base and the batter is running towards first.

If the second baseman with the ball steps on first base, who is out and who is safe?

If the second baseman steps on first, do they still have a force on 2nd base?

Comment: Thanks for posting - I did not see this earlier. https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/97/if-a-play-ends-with-two-runners-at-the-same-base-who-is-safe

Answer (score -1):

The batter is out and the runner is no longer forced at second. It's just the same as if the runner took a step off 1st, the 2nd-baseman stepped on 1st and then the runner went back to first.